# Delete only image from database mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, view, edit

Oke so I have a table in my SQL server DB that look like:

```
QUESTION
__________
id     | int
weight | int
title  | varchar
image  | varbinary
...
```

Now I made an admin panel where you can edit the values of the field and where you can choose a new picture that you can upload. But in this edit view I also want users to be able to delete only that image. How can I do this?

this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        <h4>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.title, new { cols = 50, @rows = 3 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <h4>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.text)
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.text, new { cols = 50, @rows = 3 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.text)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <h4>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.weight)
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.weight)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.weight)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <h4>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.difficulty)
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.difficulty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.difficulty)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <h4>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.image)
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.image)
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name="imgUserProfile" id="imgUserProfile" title="Browse" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
                </span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 250px" readonly>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
          <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 200px; " />
         <br />

        </div>
    <br />

    <h2>Statements</h2>
    @Html.ActionLink("add statement", "Create", "Statement", new { id = Model.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-default" })
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.Action("_StatementPerQuestion", "Question", new { id = Model.id })
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class=" btn btn-success" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can render the image and put a button to delete it when the user clicks it makes you invisible. After clicking the button you save a boolean value to a hidden field in your controller so you know whether or not he wants to delete the image.

After you retrieve data from the database by id that is in view, so you get the populated object and passes null for the column base. Its base must accept null field

Comment: I found a solution myself and it is based on the same principal. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself, but it is pretty simular to the one of @Daniel Melo.

I added a button who passes the id of the question which calls this function in my controller

```
 public ActionResult DeletePic(int id = 0)
    {

        question question = db.question.Find(id);
        if (question == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                question.image = null;
                db.Entry(question).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Question", new { id = question.id });
            }
        }
        return View(question);

    }
```